# template with lambda as unique default parameter on each instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, c++20

I'm looking for a way to automatically make default template parameter be unique each time a template is instantiated. Since unnamed function objects created by lambda expressions have different types I thought of adopting them somehow. With recent changes to standard daft removing *"A lambda-expression shall not appear in ... a template-argument"* restriction (see [Wording for lambdas in unevaluated contexts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r3.pdf)) it seemed like a good idea. So I wrote the following kinda working snippet that [compiles on recent gcc and clang](https://godbolt.org/z/mFpdp8):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<void ( * ) (void) = [](){}> class
unique final {};

static_assert(false == ::std::is_same_v<unique<>, unique<>>);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is this a viable approach or one of those "ill-formed, no diagnostic is required" cases?

Some additional context: I want to use this to implement Ada-style strong type definitions that should work in a single translation unit without manually inventing unique tags that would be otherwise unused:

```
struct _tag_WowInt {};
using Int = type<int, _tag_WowInt>;
struct _tag_SoUnique {};
using DifferentInt = type<int, _tag_SoUnique>;
```

Upd1: I would like to mention that approaches involving `__COUNTER__` or similar macros won't work in general case because they will be expanded by preprocessor only once and [won't yield unique types when used inside of template for example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5V7TfJT1xpS3yIBg).

Comment: msvc and edg reject your code for different reasons even; interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are right, it seems to me that is "ill-formed, no diagnostic required". I think this is covered by
[[temp.res/8.4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.4) and [[temp.res/8.5]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.res#8.5):

> (8.4) ― a hypothetical instantiation of a template immediately following its definition would be ill-formed due to
>   a construct that does not depend on a template parameter, or
>
> (8.5) ― the interpretation of such a construct in the hypothetical instantiation is **different from the interpretation
>    of the corresponding construct in any actual instantiation of the template**. [*Note*: This can happen in situations including the following:
>
> (8.5.1) ― a type used in a non-dependent name is incomplete at the point at which a template is defined but is complete at the point at which an instantiation is performed, or
>
> (8.5.2) ― lookup for a name in the template definition found a using-declaration, but the lookup in the corresponding scope in the instantiation does not find any declarations because the using-declaration was a pack expansion and the corresponding pack is empty, or
>
> (8.5.3) ― an instantiation uses a default argument or default template argument that had not been defined at the point at which the template was defined, or
>
> (8.5.4) ― constant expression evaluation within the template instantiation uses
>
> (8.5.4.1) ― the value of a const object of integral or unscoped enumeration type or
>
> (8.5.4.2) ― the value of a constexpr object or
>
> (8.5.4.3) ― the value of a reference or
>
> (8.5.4.4) ― the definition of a constexpr function,
>   and that entity was not defined when the template was defined, or
>
> (8.5.5) ― a class template specialization or variable template specialization that is specified by a non-dependent simple-template-id is used by the template, and either it is instantiated from a partial specialization that was not defined when the template was defined or it names an explicit specialization that was not declared when the template was defined.
>   — *end note*]

Even though your use case is not explicitly listed in the examples of the note, in my understanding the requirement implies that `unique<>` must refer to the same thing throughout the whole program, otherwise it is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

This was [CWG1850](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1850). The Committee appear to dislike this
kind of stateful meta-programming. The [`constexpr` counter](http://b.atch.se/posts/constexpr-counter/) no longer works
in newer versions of the compilers.

Comment: 8.4 does not seem to be applicable at all. Which construct not depending on template parameters would be ill-formed here?. And i'm not sure about 8.5 either. 1) "the construct" referenced there seems to refer to some part of the template, not to the template instantiations; 2) instantiating template with default parameters is allowed to yield different results in different scopes because default template parameters may be redefined (when used as template template parameter for example).

Comment: @VTT 8.4 does not apply, but it defines what a "hypothetical intantiation" is.

Comment: @VTT there's a newer version of the paper you linked ([P0315R4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0315r4.pdf)) where the authors claim that defining `foo<[]{}>()` in two TU should be an ODR violation.

Comment: @VTT interestingly, in GCC trunk `template<typename = decltype([]{})> class unique {}` yields always the same type (https://godbolt.org/z/SO1PZl).

Comment: @Rakete1111 I see. That enables crazy things to be made: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ACtX4SdSJqc2MOHz

Comment: @metalfox getting internal compiler error in Visual Studio 2022 on C++ 20. When I remove the default template argument, and then call the counter with: ` std::cout << counter<decltype([] {}) >() << '\n';`, it then starts to work and generates 2 functions: counts 0 to 9 two times. This compiles for me on MSVC: https://wandbox.org/permlink/giR7ZazQJyzla8VJ . Any suggestions to make this work on MSVC without macros?